# AbstractController::ActionNotFound error, even though routes.rb is configured

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a `UserController` with these methods:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  # snip

  def test_add_realtime_code
  end

  def add_realtime_code
    if request.post?
      # snip
    end
  end
end
```

In my `routes.rb`, I have this:

```
match '/user/add_realtime_code', :controller => 'user', :action => 'add_realtime_code', :via => :post
```

In `/user/test_add_realtime_code.html.erb`, I have a button that sends an AJAX POST request to `/user/add_realtime_code`:

```
<div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#test_button').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/user/add_realtime_code',
          dataType: 'text',
          data: { /* snip */ },
          success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $('#result').html(textStatus + ': ' + data);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
  <input type="button" name="test_button" id="test_button" value="test"></input>
  <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

Even though I have the route set up in `routes.rb`, whenever I click on the button and send the AJAX request, I get this error:

```
AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'add_realtime_code' could not be found for UserController)
```

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I accidentally made my `UserController#test_add_realtime_code` and `#add_realtime_code` methods `private`:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  # snip

  private
  # snip

  def test_add_realtime_code
  end

  def add_realtime_code
    if request.post?
      # snip
    end
  end
end
```

When I moved them out of the `private` methods for the controller, everything worked as I expected:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  # snip

  def test_add_realtime_code
  end

  def add_realtime_code
    if request.post?
      # snip
    end
  end

  private
  # snip
end
```